# DragonBoard 410c—Create custom Windows 10 IoT Core image

Tags: microsoft-windows-iot

After reading the [MSDN docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/create-a-basic-image) about creating a custom Image for Windows 10 IoT Core, I'm totally overwhelmed. I installed the required tools, got the BSP for the DragonBoard 410c and started step by step from the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/iot/create-a-basic-image)

I want to create my own image with the tools provided by MS (Windows ADK / WDK / IoT CoreADK AddonKit.

I was very unsuccessful, the documentation is very weak for boards other than RPi. So is there anyone who is experienced with creating custom Images for Windows 10 IoT Core?

What I have done so far:

Downloaded and installed the following Software

```
Windows ADK 1803
Windows WDK 1803
Windows10_IoTCore_Packages_ARM32_en-us_17134 (Windows10_IoT_Core_ARM_Packages.msi)
Latest iot-adk-addonkit-master
DB410c_BSP
```

After that I launched the IotCoreShell from the iot-adk-addonkit-master and the output is as follows

```
IOTADK_ROOT : C:\iot-adk-addonkit-master
ADK_VERSION : 17134
WDK_VERSION : 17134
COREKIT_VER : 17134.1
```

I went ahead with the following commands:

```
cd .\bsptools\QCDB410C
export C:\iot-adk-addonkit-master\DB410c_BSP
buildpkg all
newproduct MyProduct QCDB410C
buildimage MyProduct Test
```

Everything went fine until the buildimage command, where I get an error and it aborts the process. Here is the error from the log

```
Creating MyProduct Test Image, see C:\iot-adk-addonkit-develop\Build\arm\MyProduct_Test.log for progress
ThreadId8768 ERROR: Please run imageapp.exe in an elevated console.
```

Of Course I did run the IoTCoreShell with admin privileges. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong or where the issue is.

Comment: Can you be more specific about where you got to? Are you looking for a full how-to for this board, or are you stuck with translating a specific step in the flow to use your BSP?

Comment: @Sean Houlihane, yes i'm looking for a full how-two, because there is nowhere a detailed guide for this specific board available. I can edit my question above as soon as i'm at home, then i can describe what i have done already, but again i have no experience with that so i don't know if i made this correct. But my goal is to learn how to build images for this specific board.

Comment: I found this with a simple search, http://robtiffany.com/get-dragonboard-running-windows-10-iot-core/ but that would not make a good answer...

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you for adding all the information. Providing *full how-to's* is still not the thing we do very well on Stack Exchange sites. Helping you out with your error however seems very much on-topic.

Comment: @Helmar if someone can give me some hints why i get this error, this should help me to test and try further and would help me very much.